# cursor does not move right when trying to edit crontab

Tags: linux, cron, vi

I run "crontab -e" to try to modify cron jobs... when editor opens, I move the cursor down to point to the line I need to change. Then I press right arrow or l key to move to the right, but only a beep is heard. No movement occurs.

Editor is in command mode.

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Never mind... I know how to change default editor

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting this as a quote, I was getting "your post appears to contain code". Anyone who knows how to fix it, please feel free to edit.

> If you ever need to know how to use Vi again, <kbd>h</kbd>
>   <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> will move you around in vi
>   (left, down, up, right, respectively).
>
> Press <kbd>i</kbd> to start typing
>
> Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to stop typing and start moving again.
>
> After pressing <kbd>esc</kbd>,  type
>   <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to save and 
>   <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to exit.
>
> Pressing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> will
>   save and exit.
>
> This is the most basic use of vi and using it purely like this isn't
>   worth it, it's recommended to learn how to use it properly if you
>   wan't to use it as an editor.
>
> However, this will help you use it atleast basically when there is no
>   other choice.